# Using XMLVM to port iPhone app to Android?

Tags: iphone, android, port

I'm considering writing an app for both platforms, but the iPhone app must be bug-free and on time, so I want to write it first.  I have no experience with either platform.

It would appear to be that applications written for Android in Java can be converted (imperfectly) to Objective C using XMLVM, after which one could fix it up and make it work with a lot less work.

My question is, can it be done the other way around?  I don't see a theoretical reason why it can't, but I haven't found anything that suggests that it's been implemented.  (Of course, I'm not fixated on XMLVM; if there's a different solution, I'd be happy to use it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done.

XMLVM converts bytecode (JVM bytecode, .NET bytecode, or Ruby YARV bytecode) to several different languages, including Objective C.  It can't convert Objective C source or compiled code.